# Numerical Root-finding Algorithms for Continous Piecewise Functions

Tags: functions, numerical-methods, roots, piecewise-continuity

I have this function:
$$f(x)=10^4(\sin^2(\frac{33}{x} \pi)+\sin^2(x\pi))$$
$$g(x)=\begin{cases}f(x)<10:f(x)\\f(x) \geq 10:10
\end{cases}$$
How would I find a root of $g(x)$, given I have an interval where only one root must be? Is there a way to figure out if any value is below 10 in any interval?

Comment: $g(x)=\max(f(x),10)$

Comment: @saulspatz Probably should have added "elementary functions". But... clever.

Comment: Well, $f(x)\leq 2$, so you can use $g(x) = 10$

Comment: @saulspatz Fixed question.

Comment: You must provide an explicit list of allowed functions.

Comment: @YvesDaoust But that would be a long list.

Comment: @QuoteDave: I doubt it. But if you think of a long list, I can even less guess what you have in mind. Jabcobi Theta, Airy, Inverse Elliptic… ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I changed my question, as your comment realized I wasn't really sure what I was looking for.

Comment: Please ask a new question, do not edit to change the question so completely that the present answers appear unconnected.

Answer (score 1):

$g(x)\ge10$ so that $g$ has no root.

Comment: Whoops. I wrote it wrong (again). Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: I have fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a bound on the root, you can use the bisection method. For more information about the bisection method, you can look here:
     [Wikipedia Article on bisection method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method)
However, it does not use integration.

Bob

Comment: I know about bisection, however, all I said that there is a bound $[a,b]$ where one root must lie in. However, $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ are both positive.